# Magento 2.4.2 How to attched PDF in Email?

Tags: magento2.4.2

I want to attach PDF in custom Email template but it not working having some error like

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function createAttachment() on null in /var/www/html/app/code/Magento360/Base/Model/Mail/TransportBuilder.php:8
Stack trace:
ù0 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento360/Base/Model/Mail/TransportBuilder/Interceptor.php(23):
```

I have tried following solution but non of are working for me

1. https://webkul.com/blog/attach-pdf-file-magento-2-email/
2. https://meetanshi.com/blog/programmatically-attach-pdf-file-in-magento-2-email/
3. https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-email-attachments/issues/4

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with my code? is there anything changed in 2.4.2 for File Attachment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here custom career module code with a file attachment in an email.
> [You can download the whole code from here](https://github.com/mitaldeveloper/magento2-email-attachments)
>
> 1. Controller sends email action with attachment.
>    Mital/Careers/Controller/Index/Save.php

```
<?php
namespace Mital\Careers\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context; 
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Save extends Action
{   
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    
    protected $_modelDataFactory;
 
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,       
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploader,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Mital\Careers\Model\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
    )
    {           
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->uploader = $uploader;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        parent::__construct($context);        
    }
    public function execute()
    {  

     try{
        $request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();    

        if(isset($_FILES['myfile']) && isset($_FILES['myfile']['name']) && strlen($_FILES['myfile']['name'])){
            $base_media_path = 'Mital/Careers';
            $uploader = $this->uploader->create(
                ['fileId' => 'myfile']
            );                
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['pdf','doc','docx','odt']);               
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $result = $uploader->save(
                $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($base_media_path)
            );                
            $data['myfile'] = $base_media_path.$result['file'];
            $filePath = $result['path'].$result['file'];
            $fileName = $result['name'];
         }

         $templateVars = [            
            'name'      => $request['your_name'],            
            'message'   => $request['your_message'],
            'email'     => $request['email_address'],
            'telephone' => $request['your_telephone']
        ];

        $fromEmail= $this->getRequest()->getPostValue('email_address');
        $fromName = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue('your_name');

        $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

        $to =  $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'contact/email/recipient_email',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );         

         $templateOptions = [
          'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
          'store' => 1
        ];        

        if(isset($fileName)){
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('careers_email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->addAttachment(file_get_contents($filePath),$fileName ,'application/pdf')
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->getTransport();
        }else{
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('careers_email_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)                
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($to)
            ->getTransport();
        }
        
             
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Form successfully submitted'));

        $redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $redirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $redirect;

    }catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
        }           
           
    }
   
}
?>
```

> 2. Create a custom transport builder for send an attachment Mital/Careers/Model/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Mital\Careers\Model\Mail\Template;

use Magento\Framework\App\TemplateTypesInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\AddressConverter;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MimePartInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\FactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TemplateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Zend\Mime\Mime;
use Zend\Mime\PartFactory;

/**
 * TransportBuilder
 *
 * @api
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{
    /**
     * Template Identifier
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $templateIdentifier;

    /**
     * Template Model
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $templateModel;

    /**
     * Template Variables
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $templateVars;

    /**
     * Template Options
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $templateOptions;

    /**
     * Mail Transport
     *
     * @var TransportInterface
     */
    protected $transport;

    /**
     * Template Factory
     *
     * @var FactoryInterface
     */
    protected $templateFactory;

    /**
     * Object Manager
     *
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * Message
     *
     * @var EmailMessageInterface
     */
    protected $message;

    /**
     * Sender resolver
     *
     * @var SenderResolverInterface
     */
    protected $_senderResolver;

    /**
     * @var TransportInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $mailTransportFactory;

    /**
     * Param that used for storing all message data until it will be used
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $messageData = [];

    /**
     * @var EmailMessageInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $emailMessageInterfaceFactory;

    /**
     * @var MimeMessageInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory;

    /**
     * @var MimePartInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $mimePartInterfaceFactory;

    /**
     * @var AddressConverter|null
     */
    private $addressConverter;

    protected $attachments = [];

    protected $partFactory;

    /**
     * TransportBuilder constructor
     *
     * @param FactoryInterface $templateFactory
     * @param MessageInterface $message
     * @param SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory
     * @param MessageInterfaceFactory|null $messageFactory
     * @param EmailMessageInterfaceFactory|null $emailMessageInterfaceFactory
     * @param MimeMessageInterfaceFactory|null $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory
     * @param MimePartInterfaceFactory|null $mimePartInterfaceFactory
     * @param addressConverter|null $addressConverter
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        FactoryInterface $templateFactory,
        MessageInterface $message,
        SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory,
        MessageInterfaceFactory $messageFactory = null,
        EmailMessageInterfaceFactory $emailMessageInterfaceFactory = null,
        MimeMessageInterfaceFactory $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = null,
        MimePartInterfaceFactory $mimePartInterfaceFactory = null,
        AddressConverter $addressConverter = null
    ) {
        $this->templateFactory = $templateFactory;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_senderResolver = $senderResolver;
        $this->mailTransportFactory = $mailTransportFactory;
        $this->emailMessageInterfaceFactory = $emailMessageInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
            ->get(EmailMessageInterfaceFactory::class);
        $this->mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
            ->get(MimeMessageInterfaceFactory::class);
        $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory = $mimePartInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
            ->get(MimePartInterfaceFactory::class);
        $this->addressConverter = $addressConverter ?: $this->objectManager
            ->get(AddressConverter::class);
        $this->partFactory = $objectManager->get(PartFactory::class);
        parent::__construct($templateFactory, $message, $senderResolver, $objectManager, $mailTransportFactory, $messageFactory, $emailMessageInterfaceFactory, $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory,
            $mimePartInterfaceFactory, $addressConverter);
    }

    /**
     * Add cc address
     *
     * @param array|string $address
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addCc($address, $name = '')
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('cc', $address, $name);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add to address
     *
     * @param array|string $address
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function addTo($address, $name = '')
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('to', $address, $name);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add bcc address
     *
     * @param array|string $address
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function addBcc($address)
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('bcc', $address);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set Reply-To Header
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @param string|null $name
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function setReplyTo($email, $name = null)
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('replyTo', $email, $name);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set mail from address
     *
     * @param string|array $from
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     * @see setFromByScope()
     *
     * @deprecated 102.0.1 This function sets the from address but does not provide
     * a way of setting the correct from addresses based on the scope.
     */
    public function setFrom($from)
    {
        return $this->setFromByScope($from);
    }

    /**
     * Set mail from address by scopeId
     *
     * @param string|array $from
     * @param string|int $scopeId
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws MailException
     * @since 102.0.1
     */
    public function setFromByScope($from, $scopeId = null)
    {
        $result = $this->_senderResolver->resolve($from, $scopeId);
        $this->addAddressByType('from', $result['email'], $result['name']);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set template identifier
     *
     * @param string $templateIdentifier
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTemplateIdentifier($templateIdentifier)
    {
        $this->templateIdentifier = $templateIdentifier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set template model
     *
     * @param string $templateModel
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTemplateModel($templateModel)
    {
        $this->templateModel = $templateModel;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set template vars
     *
     * @param array $templateVars
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTemplateVars($templateVars)
    {
        $this->templateVars = $templateVars;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set template options
     *
     * @param array $templateOptions
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
    {
        $this->templateOptions = $templateOptions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get mail transport
     *
     * @return TransportInterface
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function getTransport()
    {
        try {
            $this->prepareMessage();
            $mailTransport = $this->mailTransportFactory->create(['message' => clone $this->message]);
        } finally {
            $this->reset();
        }

        return $mailTransport;
    }

    /**
     * Reset object state
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function reset()
    {
        $this->messageData = [];
        $this->templateIdentifier = null;
        $this->templateVars = null;
        $this->templateOptions = null;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get template
     *
     * @return TemplateInterface
     */
    protected function getTemplate()
    {
        return $this->templateFactory->get($this->templateIdentifier, $this->templateModel)
            ->setVars($this->templateVars)
            ->setOptions($this->templateOptions);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare message.
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws LocalizedException if template type is unknown
     */
    protected function prepareMessage()
    {
        $template = $this->getTemplate();
        $content = $template->processTemplate();
        switch ($template->getType()) {
            case TemplateTypesInterface::TYPE_TEXT:
                $part['type'] = MimeInterface::TYPE_TEXT;
                break;

            case TemplateTypesInterface::TYPE_HTML:
                $part['type'] = MimeInterface::TYPE_HTML;
                break;

            default:
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    new Phrase('Unknown template type')
                );
        }
        $mimePart = $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory->create(['content' => $content]);
        $parts = count($this->attachments) ? array_merge([$mimePart], $this->attachments) : [$mimePart];
        $this->messageData['body'] = $this->mimeMessageInterfaceFactory->create(
            ['parts' => $parts]
        );

        $this->messageData['subject'] = html_entity_decode(
            (string)$template->getSubject(),
            ENT_QUOTES
        );
        $this->message = $this->emailMessageInterfaceFactory->create($this->messageData);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Handles possible incoming types of email (string or array)
     *
     * @param string $addressType
     * @param string|array $email
     * @param string|null $name
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    private function addAddressByType(string $addressType, $email, ?string $name = null): void
    {
        if (is_string($email)) {
            $this->messageData[$addressType][] = $this->addressConverter->convert($email, $name);
            return;
        }
        $convertedAddressArray = $this->addressConverter->convertMany($email);
        if (isset($this->messageData[$addressType])) {
            $this->messageData[$addressType] = array_merge(
                $this->messageData[$addressType],
                $convertedAddressArray
            );
        } else {
        $this->messageData[$addressType] = $convertedAddressArray;
    }
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $content
     * @param string|null $fileName
     * @param string|null $fileType
     * @return TransportBuilder
     */
    public function addAttachment(?string $content, ?string $fileName, ?string $fileType)
    {
        $attachmentPart = $this->partFactory->create();
        $attachmentPart->setContent($content)
            ->setType($fileType)
            ->setFileName($fileName)
            ->setDisposition(Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT)
            ->setEncoding(Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);
        $this->attachments[] = $attachmentPart;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

[You can download module for custom form with email attachment from here](https://github.com/mitaldeveloper/magento2-email-attachments)

Comment: i tried this 2.4.2 not working

Comment: which error are you facing?

Comment: I am using 2.4.0 but getting error

Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder\Interceptor::addAttachment().

Comment: I made changes on the above code

Comment: After trying many solutions, this one only seems to be working. Thanks (v2.4.5-p1).

Answer (score 1):

I used this class in a custom module, but instead of using preference or extending the class, or doing both, it did not work, because I was not able to set the values to the parent class properties in this location, so re-written the entire class as a new one without extending or using preference and it worked, please find the code below.

```
enter code here
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace OX\MailAttachment\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\FactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\TemplateTypesInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\AddressConverter;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MimeMessageInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\MimePartInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TemplateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\TransportInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Zend\Mime\Part;
use Zend_Mime;

/**
 * TransportBuilder for Mail Templates
 *
 * @api
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Transport
{
    public $attachments;
    /**
     * Template Identifier
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $templateIdentifier;
    /**
     * Template Model
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $templateModel;
    /**
     * Template Variables
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $templateVars;
    /**
     * Template Options
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $templateOptions;
    /**
     * Mail Transport
     *
     * @var TransportInterface
     */
    protected $transport;
    /**
     * Template Factory
     *
     * @var FactoryInterface
     */
    protected $templateFactory;
    /**
     * Object Manager
     *
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;
    /**
     * Message
     *
     * @var MessageInterface
     */
    protected $message;
    /**
     * Sender resolver
     *
     * @var SenderResolverInterface
     */
    protected $_senderResolver;
    /**
     * @var TransportInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $mailTransportFactory;
    /**
     * Param that used for storing all message data until it will be used
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $messageData = [];
    /**
     * @var EmailMessageInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $emailMessageInterfaceFactory;
    /**
     * @var MimeMessageInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory;
    /**
     * @var MimePartInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $mimePartInterfaceFactory;
    /**
     * @var AddressConverter|null
     */
    private $addressConverter;

    /**
     * TransportBuilder constructor
     *
     * @param FactoryInterface $templateFactory
     * @param MessageInterface $message
     * @param SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param TransportInterfaceFactory $mailTransportFactory
     * @param MessageInterfaceFactory|null $messageFactory
     * @param EmailMessageInterfaceFactory|null $emailMessageInterfaceFactory
     * @param MimeMessageInterfaceFactory|null $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory
     * @param MimePartInterfaceFactory|null $mimePartInterfaceFactory
     * @param addressConverter|null $addressConverter
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        FactoryInterface             $templateFactory,
        MessageInterface             $message,
        SenderResolverInterface      $senderResolver,
        ObjectManagerInterface       $objectManager,
        TransportInterfaceFactory    $mailTransportFactory,
        MessageInterfaceFactory      $messageFactory = null,
        EmailMessageInterfaceFactory $emailMessageInterfaceFactory = null,
        MimeMessageInterfaceFactory  $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = null,
        MimePartInterfaceFactory     $mimePartInterfaceFactory = null,
        AddressConverter             $addressConverter = null
    ) {
        $this->templateFactory = $templateFactory;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_senderResolver = $senderResolver;
        $this->mailTransportFactory = $mailTransportFactory;
        $this->emailMessageInterfaceFactory = $emailMessageInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
            ->get(EmailMessageInterfaceFactory::class);
        $this->mimeMessageInterfaceFactory = $mimeMessageInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
            ->get(MimeMessageInterfaceFactory::class);
        $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory = $mimePartInterfaceFactory ?: $this->objectManager
            ->get(MimePartInterfaceFactory::class);
        $this->addressConverter = $addressConverter ?: $this->objectManager
            ->get(AddressConverter::class);
    }

    /**
     * Add cc address
     *
     * @param array|string $address
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addCc($address, $name = '')
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('cc', $address, $name);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Handles possible incoming types of email (string or array)
     *
     * @param string $addressType
     * @param string|array $email
     * @param string|null $name
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    private function addAddressByType(string $addressType, $email, ?string $name = null): void
    {
        if (is_string($email)) {
            $this->messageData[$addressType][] = $this->addressConverter->convert($email, $name);
            return;
        }
        $convertedAddressArray = $this->addressConverter->convertMany($email);
        if (isset($this->messageData[$addressType])) {
            $this->messageData[$addressType] = array_merge(
                $this->messageData[$addressType],
                $convertedAddressArray
            );
        } else {
            $this->messageData[$addressType] = $convertedAddressArray;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add to address
     *
     * @param array|string $address
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function addTo($address, $name = '')
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('to', $address, $name);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add bcc address
     *
     * @param array|string $address
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function addBcc($address)
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('bcc', $address);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set Reply-To Header
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @param string|null $name
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function setReplyTo($email, $name = null)
    {
        $this->addAddressByType('replyTo', $email, $name);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set mail from address
     *
     * @param string|array $from
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     * @see setFromByScope()
     *
     * @deprecated 102.0.1 This function sets the from address but does not provide
     * a way of setting the correct from addresses based on the scope.
     */
    public function setFrom($from)
    {
        return $this->setFromByScope($from);
    }

    /**
     * Set mail from address by scopeId
     *
     * @param string|array $from
     * @param string|int $scopeId
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws MailException
     * @since 102.0.1
     */
    public function setFromByScope($from, $scopeId = null)
    {
        $result = $this->_senderResolver->resolve($from, $scopeId);
        $this->addAddressByType('from', $result['email'], $result['name']);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set template identifier
     *
     * @param string $templateIdentifier
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTemplateIdentifier($templateIdentifier)
    {
        $this->templateIdentifier = $templateIdentifier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set template model
     *
     * @param string $templateModel
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTemplateModel($templateModel)
    {
        $this->templateModel = $templateModel;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set template vars
     *
     * @param array $templateVars
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTemplateVars($templateVars)
    {
        $this->templateVars = $templateVars;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set template options
     *
     * @param array $templateOptions
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
    {
        $this->templateOptions = $templateOptions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get mail transport
     *
     * @return TransportInterface
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function getTransport()
    {
        try {
            $this->prepareMessage();
            $mailTransport = $this->mailTransportFactory->create(['message' => clone $this->message]);
        } finally {
            $this->reset();
        }

        return $mailTransport;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare message.
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws LocalizedException if template type is unknown
     */
    protected function prepareMessage()
    {
        $template = $this->getTemplate();
        $content = $template->processTemplate();
        switch ($template->getType()) {
            case TemplateTypesInterface::TYPE_TEXT:
                $part['type'] = MimeInterface::TYPE_TEXT;
                break;

            case TemplateTypesInterface::TYPE_HTML:
                $part['type'] = MimeInterface::TYPE_HTML;
                break;

            default:
                throw new LocalizedException(
                    new Phrase('Unknown template type')
                );
        }
        $mimePart = $this->mimePartInterfaceFactory->create(['content' => $content]);
        $parts = $this->attachments !== null ? count($this->attachments)
            ? array_merge([$mimePart], $this->attachments) : [$mimePart] : [$mimePart];
        $this->messageData['body'] = $this->mimeMessageInterfaceFactory->create(
            ['parts' => $parts]
        );
        // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
        $this->messageData['subject'] = html_entity_decode(
            (string)$template->getSubject(),
            ENT_QUOTES
        );
        $this->message = $this->emailMessageInterfaceFactory->create($this->messageData);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get template
     *
     * @return TemplateInterface
     */
    protected function getTemplate()
    {
        return $this->templateFactory->get($this->templateIdentifier, $this->templateModel)
            ->setVars($this->templateVars)
            ->setOptions($this->templateOptions);
    }

    /**
     * Reset object state
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function reset()
    {
        $this->messageData = [];
        $this->templateIdentifier = null;
        $this->templateVars = null;
        $this->templateOptions = null;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addFileAttachment($files)
    {
        foreach ($files as $index) {
            $attachment = new Part($index['attachment']);
            $attachment->type = $index['mimeType'];
            $attachment->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT;
            $attachment->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
            $attachment->filename = $index['fileName'];
            $this->attachments[] = $attachment;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

please use this class Transport.php by injecting in your controller or Helper class or Model file like this below example and call the addAttchment() method which will call that method in that class:

```
$transport = $this->transport
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
                ->setTemplateOptions([
                    'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                ])
                ->setTemplateVars($data)
                ->setFrom([
                    'name' => $senderName,
                    'email' => $senderEmail
                ])
                ->addTo($data['receiver_email'], $data['receiver_name'])
                ->addFileAttachment($files)
                ->getTransport();
```

Note , this worked for me in Magento version 2.4.1

Answer (score -1):

This should work:)

on your di.xml Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder"     type="Module\Vendor\Model\Mail\SenderBuilder"/>
```

**On Vendor\Module\Model\Order**

```
  <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Mail;


class SenderBuilder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilder
{
    /**
     * Prepare and send email message
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function send()
    {
        $vars  = $this->templateContainer->getTemplateVars();
        $order = $vars['order'];
        
        if(isset( $order))
        {
            
                $fileName = get your file name here
                $file     = get your file here;

                $this->transportBuilder->addAttachment($file, $fileName, 'application/pdf');
            
        }

        $this->configureEmailTemplate();

        $this->transportBuilder->addTo(
            $this->identityContainer->getCustomerEmail(),
            $this->identityContainer->getCustomerName()
        );

        $copyTo = $this->identityContainer->getEmailCopyTo();

        if (!empty($copyTo) && $this->identityContainer->getCopyMethod() == 'bcc') {
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $this->transportBuilder->addBcc($email);
            }
        }

        $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to atteched PDF in custom email tempalte https://prnt.sc/12geex5