# How to attach pdf in mail in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4.2

I have custom form with add file button. Once user submit the form i need to sent form details with pdf in mail.

I tried different solutions.

and i follow this - [Magento 2.4.2 How to attched PDF in Email?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/336592/magento-2-4-2-how-to-attched-pdf-in-email)

but i got error like

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Zend\Mime\PartFactory does not exist
```

so i used Laminas in place of zend then i face same error like

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Laminas\Mime\PartFactory does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento2.4 does not provide addattachment function in `TransportBuilder` Class, You need to build it.

```
 public function __construct(         
         ...
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \{{vendor}}\{{module}}\Model\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
   
    {

        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
       
        ....
    }
    public function execute()
    {       
         $templateOptions = [
          'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
          'store' => 1
        ];
        $templateVars = [
            'var1'      => 'value1',
            'var2'      => 'value2',
            'var3'      => 'value3',
            'var4'      => 'value4'
        ];
        $filePath = '/home/basic/Desktop/test.pdf';  //get your pdf file path
        $fileName = "filename.pdf";  //set your email attachment pdf name
        $fromEmail = "formemail@gmail.com"; //set from email
        $fromName = 'your name'; // set from name
        $fromdata = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];                
        $to =  $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'contact/email/recipient_email',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );                     
        $emailtempalte = 'email_tempalte'; //set our email template
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($emailtempalte)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->addAttachment(file_get_contents($filePath),$fileName ,'application/pdf')
                ->setFrom($fromdata)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        echo "message sent successfully with attachment";

    }
}
```

create new TransportBuilder class and extend it with magento `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder` class

```
namespace {{vendor}}\{{module}}\Model\Mail\Template;
class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{    
    protected $message;
    public function addAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType)
    {
        $this->message->setBodyAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType);
        return $this;
    }
    protected function prepareMessage()
    {
        parent::prepareMessage();
        $this->message->setPartsToBody();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Execute upgrade and clean cache command and check it.

[Ref Link](https://github.com/weprovide/magento2-module-mailattachment/blob/master/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php)

Comment: Hi @S.P i tried this . but i got this error 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Zend\Mime\PartFactory does not exist

Comment: is it vendor/magento/framework/Mail/MimePart.php and MimePart.php there?

Comment: execute setup:upgrade command before check. and make sure that you have no error with setup:di:compile command .

Comment: yes MimePart.php file is present

Comment: which magento version are u using?

Comment: I have changed TransportBuilder class, Replace it and check.

Comment: i am using magento commerce edition 2.4.3

Comment: HI @S.P thanku so much for your respoces. I used this transportbuilder previoulsy but i got this "error: call to undefined method SetPartstoBody()"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136353/discussion-between-mani-and-s-p).